# How do I receive a dict with a post request, json and cherrypy?

Tags: python, json, post, python-requests, cherrypy

I'm just trying to send a response to a client post request but I don't know how to decode the response. I always get a string back.

here's my server code:

```
import json
import cherryp

class Hey:

    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    def index(self):
        a = {"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}
        return json.dumps(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     cherrypy.quickstart(Hey())
```

Here's my client code:

```
import requests
import json
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}


def postServer():
    resp = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/index", headers=headers)
    return resp.json()


def test():
    response = postServer()
    print(response)


test()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server code should look like this:

```
import json
import cherrypy

class Hey:

    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    def index(self):
        a = {"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}
        return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
     cherrypy.quickstart(Hey())
```

The `json_out` will convert the dict into a valid JSON string.

Also in your client code you don't have to `import json` to use the `json` method from `requests`.